# In Asp.Net MVC 3 what constitutes a authenticated user to the AuthorizeAttribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication, authorize-attribute

I find that many things in Asp.Net is based on assumed knowledge. I for example do not know much about internet authentication and have a hard time finding anything about it on a beginner level.

One thing that is puzzling me is the AuthorizeAttribute. I understand how to use it and what it's supposed to do but I'm wondering if it will work under situations where you have a custom login system.

In the description on the AuthorizeAttribute page it says simply
`When you mark an action method with AuthorizeAttribute, access to that action method is restricted to users who are both authenticated and authorized.`

So what is a authenticated user, how do you set one user to be authenticated. If I create my own login system how do I set is so that a logged in user is authenticate enough for AuthorizeAttribute to allow him entry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It checks the IsAuthorized of the [IIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iidentity.aspx) of [IPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.aspx).

In the Global.asax add a method to handle "AuthorizeRequest". then in that method do what ever you need to check the user is authorized (check a session, cookie, db etc)

Then set the HttpContext.Current.User to a [GenericPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.genericprincipal.aspx) that has an user that implements the IIdentity and has it's IsAuthorized set to true.

Something like this:

```
  public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
  {
    public MvcApplication()
    {
      this.AuthorizeRequest += this.AuthorizedRequestEvent;
    }

    private void AuthorizedRequestEvent(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
      // do checking here with what ever you want
      bool isAuthenicated = false;

      // change this what what ever implements IIdentity
      var user = new User(); 
      user.IsAuthenticated = isAuthenicated ;
      GenericPrincipal principal;
      principal = new GenericPrincipal(user, new string[] { });
      HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
    }
   }
```

Comment: +1 - nice answer without telling the OP "go buy a book or you lack basic knowledge"

Comment: Thanks, sometimes a quick example says a lot more than a wall of text.

Comment: If I get a SAML certificate along with user authentication is that something I wan't to store somwhere, like in the cookie or HttpContext ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with SAML certificates, you might want to ask that in a separate question.

Comment: @Ingo: SAML could should be parsed and the information stored in a cookie. WIF (Windows Identity Foundation) does that for you.

Comment: @ Wiktor I thought WIF was for the other side, the authenticating authority. So there are tools for consumers as well?

Answer (score 1):

`HttpContext.Current.User` contains the `User` object that is the currently logged in user.  While inside a `Controller` this can also be obtained from simply `User`.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention authorized - just went over authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

If you need beginner level knowledge then you need to go buy a good book.  A quick Amazon.com search shows a lot of support for Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework so that's probably a good place to start.  The value of a book like this is it will walk you through a front to back example of building a web app (including authentication).

As for security.. you do not want to build your own.. especially if you're a beginner.  It's too easy to get something wrong and end up with a mess (been there.. done that).  What you want to do is use the built in authentication.  Again a book would be a great place to start but otherwise start with the built in template and follow this [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398049.aspx).  After you've done that start reading the code and using the class names as Google search points.

Comment: There can be a lot of problems getting things shipped to locations outside of US sadly, but a book would be helpful. The built in authentication just doesn't help me in this project, I will use a part of it but people aren't authenticated locally and unless the default system supports SAML certificates there is not much it can do for me.

Answer (score 1):

You lack the basic stuff on how the ASP.NET pipeline works.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx

In particular, somewhere early is the `AuthenticateRequest` event where plugged modules could possibly set the user to be authenticated. How they do so? By setting current `HttpContext`'s `User` to something else than `null` where `Identity.IsAuthenticated` evaluates to `true`.

Since the `User` property of the context is not bound to any particular type (rather it can be any value whose type inherit from `IPrincipal`) **any** authentication provider is possible.

And the last thing - a lot of people stick with forms authentication module where the information is retrieved from the cookie.

Comment: Yes I really need to learn the basic stuff. I always wan't to know what's going on behind the scenes. Guess I should take the time. In the Web.config authentication is set to Forms, does that do something automatic for me then?

Comment: Yes. Forms means that the `User` will be resolved from a cookie by the Forms Authentication Module. Since it works almost the same way in MVC and WebForms, you can read any Forms Authentication tutorial (`MembershipProvider` and `RoleProvider` stuff etc.)